# Laravel :cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am newbie in elasticsearch and somewhere in laravel also.. I am trying to configure elasticsearch with laravel . elasticsearch is running on 9200 port. When execute below code , it throws cURL error.I never configured 1080 port. Don't knw why it's trying to connect 1080 port ? How to change this port ?

code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use Elastica\Client as ElasticaClient;

class clientController extends Controller
{
    protected $elasticsearch;
    protected $elastica;
    public function __construct()
    {


        $logger = ClientBuilder::defaultLogger('d:/your.log');


        $this->elasticsearch = ClientBuilder::create()       
            ->setLogger($logger)   
            ->setRetries(0)
            ->build();
        $elasticConfig=['host'=>"locahost",
            "port"=>9200,
            "index"=>'pets'];
        $this->elastica = new  ElasticaClient($elasticConfig);
    }
    public function elasticsearchTest(){       

        dump($this->elasticsearch);
       // echo "\n\n Retrive Doc";
        $param = [
            'index' => 'pets',
            'type' => 'dog',
            'id'=>'1'
        ];
        $res = $this->elasticsearch->get($param);
        dump($res); exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: 1080 is commonly used for a SOCKS proxy - is your system configured to use one?

Comment: I never configured that. I checked open ports  in cmd  by netstate but it's not in the list.